# I can't see any picture. Why?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I can't see any picture. Why?

```
UIImage *photoImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"http://blog.leadcritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/favorite_animal_picture.jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photoImg];
[self.view addSubview:imageView2];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because if you use the code:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"mypicture.png"];
```

The image should be on the iPhone and not loaded from a URL. From a URL you need to use the following:

```
NSString path = @"http://blog.leadcritic.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/favorite_animal_picture.jpg";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *photoImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:NO];
UIImageView *imageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:photoImg];
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the frame of  `imageView2`

```
imageView2.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 100, 100 ); // Or whatever.
```